# Where on the main panel do I put the ground wire for the sub panel?

Tags: wiring, grounding, subpanel, neutral

The main breaker panel has the grounds and neutral hooked together and has bonding screw installed. Where do I put the ground wire for the sub panel? Do I put it on the neutral bare where the white neutral is also? So the main panel would have the ground and neutral wire for sub panel on the same bar? Also should I leave bonding screw off on sub panel?

Comment: In the main they mixed grounds and neutrals on both bus bars should I move grounds to one side and neutrals to the other side and then hook up my neutral wire to sub panel on that side and the ground on the other side for sub panel . Yes they our on the same bus bar

Answer (score 3):

In the main panel, put the neutral where all the other neutrals are.   Put the ground where all the other grounds are.  Good chance they are all going to the same bus, that is fine in a main panel.

In the sub-panel, yes, ground and neutral must be separated.

Comment: In the main they mixed grounds and neutrals on both bus bars should I move grounds to one side and neutrals to the other side and then hook up my neutral wire to sub panel on that side and the ground on the other side for sub panel . Yes they our on the same bus bar

Comment: Well, in the main panel it's not required, so it's a case of "bonus points for style".

Comment: The panel is there if just 1 is mixed in the main it is a waste of time to separate them but the sub they not only need to be separated but the neutral needs to be isolated not only on separate busses.